# Swift 3 how to resolve NetService IP?

Tags: ios, ipv4, swift3, nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

Just trying Bonjour in swift 3

Here is my code , I can receive the delegate

```
func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
 print("netServiceDidResolveAddress service name \(sender.name) of type \(sender.type)," +
                "port \(sender.port), addresses \(sender.addresses)")
}
```

And here is my result

> netServiceDidResolveAddress service name Webber's Mac mini of type
>   _myapp._tcp.,port 5678, addresses Optional([<1002162e c0a80205 00000000 00000000>, <1c1e162e 00000000 fe800000 00000000 00bce7ad
>   24b4b7e8 08000000>])

c0a80205 is the IP I looking for => 192.168.2.5

And the address is [Data] , Apple says

> The addresses of the service. This is an NSArray of NSData instances,
>   each of which contains a single struct sockaddr suitable for use with
>   connect(2). In the event that no addresses are resolved for the
>   service or the service has not yet been resolved, an empty NSArray is
>   returned.

I still confuse why Data can't use .btyes ?
As Apple says "This is an NSArray of NSData instances"
But I can't use it like NSData

And how to resolve the address as readable IP string ?

I try this before , but do not get the result as I except ...

```
let thedata = NSData(bytes: sender.addresses, length: (sender.addresses?.count)!)
var storage = sockaddr_storage()
thedata.getBytes(&storage, length: sizeof(sockaddr_storage))

if Int32(storage.ss_family) == AF_INET {
    let addr4 = withUnsafePointer(&storage) {UnsafePointer<sockaddr_in>($0).pointee }
    print(inet_ntoa(addr4.sin_addr));
}
```

Any suggestion will be help , Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Here's how I did it in Swift 3.

```
func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
    guard let data = sender.addresses?.first else { return }
    data.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer:UnsafePointer<sockaddr>) -> Void in
        guard getnameinfo(pointer, socklen_t(data.count), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 else {
            return
        }
    }
    let ipAddress = String(cString:hostname)
    print(ipAddress)
}
```

Swift 5

```
var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
data.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> Void in
        let sockaddrPtr = pointer.bindMemory(to: sockaddr.self)
        guard let unsafePtr = sockaddrPtr.baseAddress else { return }
        guard getnameinfo(unsafePtr, socklen_t(data.count), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 else {
            return
        }
    }
let ipAddress = String(cString:hostname)
print(ipAddress)
```

Comment: Phil, with Swift 5 I get a warning: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead.    Could you tell me how to solve this, the documentation from Apple is way over my head.

Comment: use the suggested withUnsafeBytes method and use baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to:) to convert  See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 10):

Edited Phil Coles answer for Swift 5.0 warning free solution:

```
func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
        var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
        guard let data = sender.addresses?.first else { return }
        data.withUnsafeBytes { ptr in
            guard let sockaddr_ptr = ptr.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self) else {
                // handle error
                return
            }
            var sockaddr = sockaddr_ptr.pointee
            guard getnameinfo(sockaddr_ptr, socklen_t(sockaddr.sa_len), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 else {
                return
            }
        }
        let ipAddress = String(cString:hostname)
        print(ipAddress)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

OK ... this is not a smart answer , at least I can get the readable IP

Just use this func to get IP string

```
let bonjourDevices = [NetService]()

let bonjourDevice = bonjourDevices[0] 

let host = self.getIPV4StringfromAddress(address:bonjourDevice.addresses!)


func getIPV4StringfromAddress(address: [Data] , port : Int ) -> String{

        let data = address.first! as NSData;

        var ip1 = UInt8(0)
        data.getBytes(&ip1, range: NSMakeRange(4, 1))

        var ip2 = UInt8(0)
        data.getBytes(&ip2, range: NSMakeRange(5, 1))

        var ip3 = UInt8(0)
        data.getBytes(&ip3, range: NSMakeRange(6, 1))

        var ip4 = UInt8(0)
        data.getBytes(&ip4, range: NSMakeRange(7, 1))

        let ipStr = String(format: "%d.%d.%d.%d:%d",ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4,port);

        return ipStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't make it work with `Data`, but using `NSData`, I would use this:

```
extension NSData {
    func castToCPointer<T>() -> T {
        let mem = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: MemoryLayout<T.Type>.size)
        self.getBytes(mem, length: MemoryLayout<T.Type>.size)
         return mem.move()
    }
}
```

So we have `netServiceDidResolveAddress`:

```
func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
    if let addresses = sender.addresses, addresses.count > 0 {
        for address in addresses {
            let data = address as NSData

            let inetAddress: sockaddr_in = data.castToCPointer()
            if inetAddress.sin_family == __uint8_t(AF_INET) {
                if let ip = String(cString: inet_ntoa(inetAddress.sin_addr), encoding: .ascii) {
                    // IPv4
                    print(ip)
                }
            } else if inetAddress.sin_family == __uint8_t(AF_INET6) {
                let inetAddress6: sockaddr_in6 = data.castToCPointer()
                let ipStringBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))
                var addr = inetAddress6.sin6_addr

                if let ipString = inet_ntop(Int32(inetAddress6.sin6_family), &addr, ipStringBuffer, __uint32_t(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN)) {
                    if let ip = String(cString: ipString, encoding: .ascii) {
                        // IPv6
                        print(ip)
                    }
                }

                ipStringBuffer.deallocate(capacity: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am having the following result (storing ips in array before display):

```
["172.16.10.120", "172.16.8.251", "::", "::82c9:d9a5:2eed:1c87"]
```

Code inspired by https://gist.github.com/agrippa1994/d8c66a2ded74fb2dd801 written in Swift 2.3 and adapted for Swift 3.0

Comment: ipStringBuffer.deallocate(capacity: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN)) is depreciated. Use ipStringBuffer.deallocate() instead.